# Power Query showing error with IF logic (Token Eof expected error)

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm creating a custom column. What I want is a 1 if the string in another column says "Positive", else a 0.

Ideally, it should look like something like this:

| id | Sentiment | Positive Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Positive | 1 |
| 2 | Neutral | 0 |
| 3 | Negative | 0 |

Here's where I'm running into a problem. An error is coming up in my logic:

Code sample : Positive Tag = IF [Sentiment] = "Positive" then 1 else 0

[image: Attempt 1]

[image: Attempt 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The M language is case-sensitive. Try `if` instead of `IF`.